# How to set a background Image of Navigator in React-Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm using Navigator component in React-Native.

```
//...
render() {
    return (
        <Navigator
            ref="navigator"
            navigationBar={this.renderHeader()}
            sceneStyle={styles.container}
            initialRoute={{type: 'Home'}}
            renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)} />
    );
}
```

Now I need to set a background image fixed for all scenes, but I can't wrap Navigator component inside another View.

```
// No errors but background is ignored
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.navigatorContainer}>
            <Image source={require('image!logo-big')} style={styles.background} />  
            <Navigator
                ref="navigator"
                navigationBar={this.renderHeader()}
                sceneStyle={styles.container}
                initialRoute={{type: 'Home'}}
                renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)} />
        </View>
    );
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    },
    background: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: 1024,
        height: 768
    },
    navigatorContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FF0000'
    }
});
```

If I set the backgroundColor to class NavigatorContainer, I can see red background but it doesn't work with image.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the fix: to show the background image you must set the navigatorContainer's backgroundColor to 'transparent'.

Comment: Is this still working? no scene is rendered when I wrap Navigator inside View