# React Native : Is it possible to have a Navigator inside a View?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Because when I do so, nothing is rendered.
The final idea is to have a common background image for the whole app.
I tried to wrap Navigator inside Image, same result.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Image source={pic} style={styles.backgroundImage}></Image>
  <Navigator
    configureScene={this.configureScene}
    style={styles.app}
    initialRoute={{ component: Main }}
    renderScene={this.renderScene}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: I don't think so. You'll probably want to handle the background image as part of renderScene, but I'm mostly guessing.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319947/how-to-set-a-background-image-of-navigator-in-react-native?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @Jickson I've looked at it already. But when I do so no scene are rendered... So I was guessing new RN version coud have changed the way to do it now

Comment: Chris, your idea works, but id like to have the the background at a first level. Because I want to animate it while i do transitions to the scenes

Answer (score 12):

Just add flex: 1 to your View's style. Bada bing bada boom.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <Navigator
     configureScene={this.configureScene}
     style={styles.app}
     initialRoute={{ component: Main }}
     renderScene={this.renderScene}
   />
 </View>
```

Comment: This is genius, worked like a charm thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What puts me into error was that if container of navigator got align-items:center, I don't see it. Don't know why yet. But I'm fine enough with this solution.

```
<Image source={pic} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
            <Navigator
              configureScene={this.configureScene}
              style={styles.app}
              initialRoute={{ component: Main }}
              renderScene={this.renderScene}
            />
          </Image>
```

Style:

```
app: {
    flex: 1
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    //alignItems: 'center'
  }
```