# How do i set a background image to custom DrawerNavigator in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My issue is, that i want the image is overflowing the Drawer
and does not fit the view width

I use contentComponent to have a custom Drawer.

the answer in the link below shows kinda what i want to achieve.
The issue though is, that width and heigth are given in absolute
values. This won't be working for tablet, iphones and android phones.
Any ideas?

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
  ...ApplicationStyles.screen,
  container: {
    //marginTop: Metrics.navBarHeight,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  drawerImage: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    opacity: 0.05,
    backgroundColor: 'green'
    // resizeMode: "stretch"
  },


 render () {
    const { navigation } = this.props
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={Images.drawerBackground} style={styles.drawerImage}/>
        <ScrollView style={styles.contentContainer}>
          <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
            <DrawerButton
              iconName='ios-map'
              text='Map'
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MapView')}
            />
            <DrawerButton
              iconName='md-trending-up'
              text='Elevation'
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Elevation')}
            />
            <DrawerButton
              iconName='md-people'
              text='Friends'
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Friends')}
            />
            <DrawerButton
              iconName='md-person'
              text='Profile'
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
            />
            <DrawerButton
              iconName='md-settings'
              text='Settings'
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
            />
            <View style={styles.checkinBtn}>
              <CheckinButton
                iconName='md-pin'
                text='Checkin Location'
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
              />
            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>
            ........
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]
[How to set a background Image of Navigator in React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319947/how-to-set-a-background-image-of-navigator-in-react-native)

Comment: can u post some code and the screenshot of the overflowing image.

Comment: is that helpful? i just combined the stylesheet and the render function.

Comment: try using `ImageBackground` instead of `Image` and wrap all your elements into it https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting

Comment: I've tried the ImageBackground and it works on both Android and IOS.
If you put that as Answer i can mark it as accepted ;-) Thanks btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `ImageBackground` instead of `Image` and wrap all your elements into it 
Refer the official docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ImageBackground } from "react-native";

 <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/images/AImg.png')} style={{ width: 100, height: 100}}>

//ur view/text flows here.....

</ImageBackground>
```

import and add ImageBackground
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.