# How to set background image with react native and react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react native with react navigation v3, and I'm trying to set a background image to my entire app.
But for some reason the image doesn't display.

If I'm wrapping my Home component the background image displays as expected, but if I'm wrapping the stack navigator, the background is white. I have searched online for solutions but it doesn't seem to work.

```
const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(
  createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: {screen: Home},
      Vocabulary: {screen: Vocabulary},
      AddWord: {screen: AddWord},
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
      headerMode: 'none',
      cardStyle: {backgroundColor: 'transparent', shadowColor:'transparent'},
      transitionConfig: () => ({
        containerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
      }),
    },
 ),
);
const App = () => {
 return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={require('./src/drawable/background1.jpg')}
      style={{flex: 1}}
      resizeMode="cover">
      <Provider store={store()}>
        <AppNavigator />
      </Provider>
    </ImageBackground>
 );
};
export default App;
```

Right now I see the component, but the background is white.

Comment: Possibly related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319947/how-to-set-a-background-image-of-navigator-in-react-native?rq=1

Comment: @Perniferous I have tried it, didn't work :(

Comment: Set backgroundColor: 'transparent' and opacity: 0.5 and see if it resolves the issue.Change the opacity if it changes.

Comment: @TanmoySarker it works but affects the content that I do want to display.

Comment: Don't know how you got that done with transperent. When i tried it showed me invalid prop. Anyway,you got the solution.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a solution for **react-navigation v6.x**

Setting `cardStyle: {backgroundColor: 'transparent'}` on the `screenOptions` property for the Stack Navigator, as proposed in [@Bizkrem Muhammad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67457788/3025856), **didn't work for me**.

But, with the help of [this Github issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9811), I found a solution that sets a default background color to every screen for our `NavigatorContainer`:

```js
import {
  DefaultTheme,
  NavigationContainer,
} from '@react-navigation/native';

const navTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    background: 'transparent',
  },
};
```

Then wrap your `Navigator` or `NavigationContainer` with `<ImageBackground>`, like so:

```js
return (
    <ImageBackground source={{/* your desired uri */}}>
        <NavigationContainer theme={navTheme} >
            {/* ... */}
        </NavigationContainer>
    </ImageBackground>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, kind of crazy but it works only if you spell transperent instead of transparent. 
[The issue that answered me](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1984)
Can't believe that wrong spelling is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In createStackNavigator function set transparentCard:true will solve your issue.

```
SubmitRouter = createStackNavigator(
  {
    SignUp: CreateUser,
    Login: LoginScreen,
    Dashboard: MainScreen
  },
  {
    transparentCard: true
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added @patrick's answer to OP and worked for me.

```
const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(
  createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: {screen: Home},
      Vocabulary: {screen: Vocabulary},
      AddWord: {screen: AddWord},
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
      headerMode: 'none',
      cardStyle: {backgroundColor: 'transparent', shadowColor:'transparent'},
      transparentCard: true, 
      transitionConfig: () => ({
        containerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
      }),
    },
 ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First add your Image background with the screen with and height and `absolute` positioning.

and in the Parent Stack Navigator group, add the `screenOptions` prop and you can pass global styles for the card `cardStyle` and add `backgroundColor: "transparent"`

here is a complete snippet

```
const { width, height } = Dimentions.get("screen");

...
<NavigationContainer>
  <Image source={require("./assets/bg.png")} style={{width, height, position: "absolute"}} />
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      header: () => null,
      cardStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
      },
    }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, but with Expo Router's Tabs component. I set `sceneContainerStyle` with `backgroundColor: 'transparent'`