# Transparent Backgrounds for Screens in React Navigation 5.x

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to use the same background for every screen in an ios/android app, without having it move when the screens transition. In React Navigation 4 there was this solution: [How to set background image with react native and react navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599305/how-to-set-background-image-with-react-native-and-react-navigation):

```
const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(
  createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: {screen: Home},
      Vocabulary: {screen: Vocabulary},
      AddWord: {screen: AddWord},
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
      headerMode: 'none',
      cardStyle: {backgroundColor: 'transparent', shadowColor:'transparent'},
      transparentCard: true, 
      transitionConfig: () => ({
        containerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
      }),
    },
 ),
);
```

But now in version 5 things have changed! You can do this:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Screen2"
  component={Screen2}
  options={{
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
    cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forVerticalIOS
  }}
/>
```

You have to do it on every screen (which is fine, although awkward), but then when you navigate to a new screen, the previous screen just moves over about 25% underneath, so it's still visible, although it's off to the side a bit. It looks really awkward:
[image: first screen]
[image: second screen on top of first]

So then I thought about using a `cardStyleInterpolator` function (as described here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigationoptions-used-by-stacknavigator), however it only lets you return styles for these elements:

```
containerStyle - Style for the container view wrapping the card.
cardStyle - Style for the view representing the card.
overlayStyle - Style for the view representing the semi-transparent overlay below
shadowStyle - Style for the view representing the card shadow.
```

and not for the previous card.

How do I make it just slide away and make room for the new elements, while keeping the background stable?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by modifying the `forSlide` example in the `cardStyleInterpolator` examples from the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#animations).

The modified interpolator looks like this:

```
const forSlide = ({ current, next, inverted, layouts: { screen } }) => {
  const progress = Animated.add(
    current.progress.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [0, 1],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    }),
    next
      ? next.progress.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, 1],
          extrapolate: 'clamp',
        })
      : 0
  );

  return {
    cardStyle: {
      transform: [
        {
          translateX: Animated.multiply(
            progress.interpolate({
              inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
              outputRange: [
                screen.width,
                0,
                screen.width * -1, // change the coefficient here
              ],
              extrapolate: 'clamp',
            }),
            inverted
          ),
        },
      ],
    },
  };
};
```

What this does is that instead of moving the previous screen only 30% to the left, it moves it one full screen width to the left.

Then I just passed the `forSlide` function as a `cardStyleInterpolator` field inside of the `screenOptions` prop of the `Stack.Navigator`.

```
<Stack.Navigator
    {...otherNavigatorProps}
    screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        cardStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
        cardStyleInterpolator: forSlide,
    }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a linear gradient on every page but you could do the same with an image just make an component image.

Initially I tried to put this in the parent component and make the background transparent on the Drawer Navigation using card styles. this did not work for me.

I found cardOverlay in the doc and added a component in that and sent it back using zIndex behind everything and did some css to make it appear on the background.

I applied this to the Drawer Navigation

```
// screenOptions
  cardOverlayEnabled: true,
  cardOverlay: () => (
    <LinearGradient
      // Background Linear Gradient
      colors={['red', 'blue']}
      style={styles.background}
    />
  ),
  cardStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    opacity: 1,
  },

// styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: -100,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    height: 700,
    zIndex: -10,
  },
})
```