# How to set ImageBackground with React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Good morning,

I can't seem to use react-native's ImageBackground with react navigation. There is a white wallpaper that is default and does not want to go away.
I used dse transparent background everywhere, optional cardStyle on the navigator and the stacks but nothing to do.
On the screenshot you can see the image appear at the very top[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWyk6.png)

App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ImageBackground, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { SafeAreaProvider, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import AuthNavigator from './navigation/AuthNavigator';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={require('./assets/fond-1.png')}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
    >
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
          <NavigationContainer>
            <AuthNavigator />
          </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}
```

AuthNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import AuthIndex from '../screens/AuthScreens/AuthIndex';
import SignUp from '../screens/AuthScreens/SignUp/SignUp';
import SignIn from '../screens/AuthScreens/SignIn/SignIn';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function AuthNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerTitle: '', // hide the title by setting it to an empty string
        headerBackTitleVisible: false, // hide back title
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerShadowVisible: false,
        headerTransparent: true, // make header transparent
        cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="AuthIndex" component={AuthIndex} />
      <Stack.Screen name="AuthSignUp" component={SignUp} />
      <Stack.Screen name="AuthSignIn" component={SignIn} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I used  transparent background everywhere, optional cardStyle on the navigator and the stacks but nothing to do.
I haven't seen a recent post, and the old ones don't answer my problem.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70117826/9802900

Comment: this technique works but a problem appears: when I click on the button to navigate the first screen is displayed for 1 second on the other screen, they overlap